# Calculate the probability of not having a seat in a stadium

Tags: probability

Given a stadium with $N$ seats and $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Spectators arrive successively, and each of them gets a ticket for a seat number $n\in \{1, \ldots, N\}$ uniformly at random. Then the spectator can sit down if there is a free seat among $\{n, n+1, \ldots, n+k-1\}$, and if there is one, the spectator chooses the first such seat in the list. (Otherwise, he or she has to leave.)

After $T$ spectators have tried, there are $Q$ seated in the stadium. 
What is the probability that the next one can sit down if

a) the seats are in a row?

b) the seats are arranged in a circle (and then seat numbers and the above list $\{n, n+1, \ldots, n+k-1\}$ are to be understood $\pmod N$)?

Comment: so the $Q$ spectators already in the stadium sit randomly? and what does this have to do with time $T$?

Comment: and how is his set number $n$ generated?

Comment: @sofaruntitled When you buy a ticket, the ticket indicates your seat number (That seat is supposed to be available, but someone else could take it even if it doesn't originally belong to him). All of the $Q$ spectators originally have specific seats (Seat number written in the ticket they bought) but they don't have to sit in those specific seats (They don't have to respect the original seat number given to them). I think you can ignore $T$, the statement could be replaced by "After some time" . As i already told you $n$ is the seat number you find on the ticket when you buy it.

Comment: well the probability that you don't have a seat depends on how your original seat $n$ is generated. For your case 1, when seats in the stadium are in a linear form, if $n$ is the right most seat, no matter how big/small $H$ is, if that seat is taken, you won't have a seat. An answer is possible if you tell me when you buy ticket, your seat number $n$ is uniformly randomly generated.

Comment: Same to the $Q$ spectators, I understand that they don't have to sit at their seat but when they come to the stadium, do they pick a seat randomly or prefer to sit next to their seat? so pretty much how they decide where to sit?

Comment: @sofaruntitled Yes actually the seat number $n$ is uniformly randomly generated (I am actually stimulating the situation with a uniformly distributed hash function). for the $Q$ spectators, yes, they tend to prefer to sit next to their seat.

Comment: @sofaruntitled Do you have any news/updates ?

Comment: Typo: "If the seat is $\color{red}{\text{not}}$ already taken by some other person". The "not" shouldn't be there. Also, I suggest you modify the post reflecting the confusion user 'sofaruntitled' raised. Assuming people would read all the comments to understand the details is a bad practice. You should make the post comprehensible to a degree that doesn't have major clarity issues.